# Getting a button in flask if it is not a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi i am trying to save a wine in a database and I have materialize card here.So a user don't have to log in to search wines but when they do they are displayed with different wines.I am trying to save a wine from the displaed one when a user clicks the add button.and i couldnt figure out how to do it.Thanks for your help.

this is my display template for all wines

```
<div class="row">
    {% for w in newList %}
    <div class="col s6 m4">
      <div style="height: 570px" class="card">
          <!-- <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light teal"  style="float:right; margin: 15px"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a> -->
          <button class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light teal" type="submit" name="action">
            <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
          </button>
        </div>
          <div class="card-content">
          <span style="color: black; font-size: 22px; font-weight:normal ; line-height: 1.1" class="card-title">{{ w['name'] }}</span>
          <p><i class="material-icons">location_on</i> {{ w['region'] }}
          </p>
          <p> <i class="material-icons">attach_money</i> {{ w['price'] }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

route

```
@app.route('/save/<string:id>',method=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def save(id):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:


    # saveWine=UserChoice()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a form, you would need to add an onClick() action on that button and configure an ajax request to call the route.

Without ajax, you'll need to create a form.

Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to learn how you can implement ajax requests.